# How to deal with unicode accented characters in JtR?

Tags: passwords

How do I configure john the ripper to ensure that it eventually cracks passphrases that might include accented characters? I want my automated weak passphrase checker to catch the use of pässwôrd.

I generated an example with:

```
mkpasswd  -m sha-512 -S frenchaccent §¤«æàâçèéêëîïô-.ùûü∞»_
```

`$6$frenchaccent$Jb/0GJhc.nLIzedOEY6QwdIpakBwyd9Z.AfzNEBXghU7bqNepOCgrLLvDV5dq6HRXiebThqyMzdzcpwbJgc6T0`

and haven't managed to crack it with john even with a wordlist of one word that was the same as the passphrase.

I'm open to hashcat, (or some other tool) if that would be better, but my existing audit tool uses john and crunch.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to do this with John.

Doing it with hashcat is currently [a bit complex](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/154958/6203), and involves bruteforcing each byte of multibyte characters.